# Как получить только путь до файла QT?

Tags: qt, c++

Добрый день.

Вот так вот я выбираю файл:

```
QString src = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open HTML"), "D:/", tr("HTML files (*.html)"));
```

Как мне сохранить, допустим, в переменную path только путь без имени файла?

Comment: @vlzkonopatov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

```
QDir(src).absolutePath()
```

Comment: QString path = QFileInfo(src).path()